# Force close my app on device turn on

Tags: android, forceclose

when ever i restart my Android 4.0 it shows my application force closed alert on home screen.And when got to my app it open perfectly.. i deal SQL lite concept in my app..does it cause this error..?

My log cat when i turn on my device:

```
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.sree.weekdayview.calendar.AnCalReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sree.weekdayview.calendar.AnCalReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sree.weekdayview.calendar-1.apk]
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1952)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1077)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sree.weekdayview.calendar.AnCalReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sree.weekdayview.calendar-1.apk]
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1947)
02-11 15:56:12.890: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: Post the logcat error you are getting. Look into how to debug your application

Comment: it would be great somehow post some code in your problem so that it is easier to identify the problem

Comment: Actually i can not monitor my log cat when i restart my device..that is why i dint post my logcat...

Comment: Why not? And why restart your device? The question talks about rotating your device. So what is it? Without logcat no one can help you. Whenever an app force close can happen, your system is in a  state where you can access logcat.

Answer (score 0):

It delivered from several issues.
If you don't have any same issue when you click power button to turn off the device(not power off, just screen off), it may not be a destroying and creation problem.

Restarting problem would mainly occur from misusing of Service.
You have to write down more details including logcat to get a right answer ;p

Comment: Actually i can not monitor my log cat when i restart my device..that is why i dint post my logcat...

Comment: Try to use ACRA(http://code.google.com/p/acra/). You can get the error report through this lib